# How to register multiple external listeners to the same selection in d3?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, d3.js

I'm writing a project in d3 in which I have an html page incorporating two external javascript files, say **script_1.js** and **script_2.js**.
I need to register one event listener from script_1.js and another from script_2.js for the change event on a select element.
At present I have this line in my html:

```
<select id="timebasis" class="selector" onchange="selectIndexSp(this),selectIndexBt(this)">
```

where **selectIndexSp(object)** and **selectIndexBt(object)** are defined respectively in script_1.js and script_2.js. I don't like this approach at all, and I'd like to know how to perform the same task in d3 rather than in the html file, which I know isn't a good practice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can add a namespace to the event name like:

```
d3.select("#timebasis")
    .on("change.sp", listenersp)
    .on("change.bt", listenerbt);
```

See: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on

> If an event listener was already registered for the same type on the
>   selected element, the existing listener is removed before the new
>   listener is added. To register multiple listeners for the same event
>   type, the type may be followed by an optional namespace, such as
>   "click.foo" and "click.bar". To remove a listener, pass null as the
>   listener.

The functions are being passed the current datum `d` and index `i`, with the `this` context as the current DOM element. It looks like your two function expect the DOM element as argument? In that case it would look like:

```
d3.select("#timebasis")
    .on("change.sp", function() { selectIndexSp(this); })
    .on("change.bt", function() { selectIndexBt(this); });
```

Comment: Thanks. I read also the wiki and I was puzzled about the namespace thing, now I got what it meant.
Both functions expect receving the select node itself as an argument, so your example just works pretty well.

Comment: PS: Forgot to add that this snippet should have d and i explicitly passed into arguments in order to work:
    `d3.select("#timebasis")
        .on("change.sp", function(d,i) { selectIndexSp(this); })
        .on("change.bt", function(d,i) { selectIndexBt(this); });`
otherwise the functions will be fired just at the select's load and not change, as usual.

Comment: Hmmmm, strange. That should not be necessary. If you don't use d, or i, you would not need to specify them. What happened when you left them out?

Comment: Edited my last comment ;). Indeed this happens every time i use the d3.on() function  and it's a known problem, I read about the solution here on github but can't find the actual question right now.  When I find it I'll post it here for reference, if you wish.

Comment: From your description it sounds like you tried to do the following: d3.select("#timebasis")
    .on("change.sp", selectIndexSp(this))
    .on("change.bt", selectIndexBt(this));

Comment: Oh, sorry. You're right. Didn't mean to make you waste time, I was convinced I pasted your code straightforward.