# D3 zoom behavior with multiple containers for a chart in one svg

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, zooming, scatter-plot

Currently, I have one SVG, which has multiple containers inside it, ie., multiple smaller svg's , which rendered according to the number of groups in the json data. If there are 5 groups of data in the json, 5 smaller multiple containers will fit into that one outer svg.

Also, if a container is zoomed, the other containers should reflect the same zoom behavior and should be in sync. This is to be implemented on scatterplot and multi-line chart.

The current problem is the multiple containers are rendered as desired, but the only the last container when zoomed in the behavior is correct. On other containers, when the zoom function is called, the zoom behavior is incorrect,ie., consider it being a scatterplot chart, the bubbles on scale and the axis do not zoom in or out.

**1) How do I bring the axis to zoom in the other containers as well, assuming the selection of the axis in the other containers are correct?

2) How do I synchronize the zoom behavior in all the containers, regardless of whichever container I zoom on?**

CODE :

```
    d3.select(that.selector+" #svgContainer"+index)
      .call(d3.behavior.zoom()
      .x(that.xScale)
      .y(that.yScale)
      .scaleExtent([1, 10])
      .on("zoom", zoomed)); /*Attaching Zoom behavior to each container id '#svgContainer0','#svgContainer1',so on.*/

    function zoomed() {
        that.zoomed_out = false;
        that.k.isOrdinal(that.selector,"#"+this.id+" .x.axis",that.xScale);
        isOrdinal(that.selector,"#"+this.id+" .x.grid",that.xScale);
        isOrdinal(that.selector,"#"+this.id+" .y.axis",that.yScale);
        isOrdinal(that.selector,"#"+this.id+" .y.grid",that.yScale);

        that.optionalFeatures()
            .plotCircle()
            .label();
        d3.select(that.selector)
            .selectAll(".dot")
            .attr("r", function (d) {
                return that.sizes(d.weight)*d3.event.scale;
            });
    };

    function isOrdinal(svg,container,scale) {
        var l = container.length;
        var temp = container.substr((l-7),7);
        if(temp === ".x.axis") {                                
                d3.select(svg).select(container).call(makeXAxis(options,scale));
            }
            else if(temp === ".y.axis") {
                d3.select(svg).select(container).call(makeYAxis(options,scale));
            }
    };

    function makeXAxis(options,xScale) {
    var xaxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xScale)
                    .ticks(options.axis.x.no_of_ticks)
                    .tickSize(options.axis.x.tickSize)
                    .outerTickSize(options.axis.x.outer_tick_size)
                    .tickPadding(options.axis.x.ticksPadding)
                    .orient(options.axis.x.orient);
    return xaxis;
};

    function makeYAxis(options,yScale) {
    var yaxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(yScale)
                    .orient(options.axis.y.orient)
                    .ticks(options.axis.y.no_of_ticks)
                    .tickSize(options.axis.y.tickSize)
                    .outerTickSize(options.axis.y.outer_tick_size)
                    .tickPadding(options.axis.y.ticksPadding);
    return yaxis;
};
```

Comment: have a look at tree map .. it might help (don't know) http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/treemap.html and the source code                                        https://secure.polisci.ohio-state.edu/faq/d3/zoomabletreemap_code.php

Comment: @Alok No that is a one dimensional chart and and also consists of one svg. Doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: see the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749182/how-to-register-multiple-external-listeners-to-the-same-selection-in-d3 may be relevant

Answer (score 0):

I might be too late but here is my take on the problem:

Basically each `.call(d3.behavior.zoom()...)` is independent and only the last one catches the event fired. Have you tried creating your own event and manually redispatching it to a list of predeclared zooms?

`.on("d3Zoom", function(){
    //zoom1
    //zoom2
    //...
    })`

Also, instead of looping through the IDs that are only regexps of #svgContainer+index, use classes: class=svgContainer, id=index.
This way you can `selectAll(".svgContainer").call(d3Zoom...)`. [The way selections are implemented as joints](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/), that may take care your independent zooming issues (selectAll represents a single selection which will be associated with one zoom whereas a loop of select represent multiple selections, hence the independent zooming capabilities).

I hope it helps someone.