# how to add additional handler to same Element with same event handler perexisted in D3

Tags: d3.js, event-handling

All:

I use D3 bind a handler to a DIV click event, then after that, I want to add some more functions to same click handler, I wonder how to do that?

Like:

```
<div id="test">TEST MULTI CLICK event handler</div>


d3.select("#test")
  .on("click", function(){
      alert("First click!");    
  })
d3.select("#test")
  .on("click", function(){
      d3.select(this).on("click")();
      alert("And this is second click!");    
  });
```

But I got "undefined is not a function" at  d3.select(this).on("click")();

Could anyone help me with this.

Thanks

**[UPDATE] Yony's solution works for me**

```
d3.select("#test")
  .on("click.init", function(){
      alert("First click!");    
  })
d3.select("#test")
  .on("click.customize", function(){
      alert("And this is second click!");  
  });
```

Comment: You can't, you need to put all the code you want to execute in the same handler, or define a function that you call from there and redefine that function as appropriate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to register multiple external listeners to the same selection in d3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749182/how-to-register-multiple-external-listeners-to-the-same-selection-in-d3)

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks,  Yony's solution seems work, just share with you.