# Adding a transform to scale a node not working as I'd expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Let me preface this by saying I'm not even 100% sure that this **should** work. I *totally apologize* for ignorance in this subject; it's something I'm very new to.

I am using a `Force Layout` like this:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .charge(-1500)
  .linkDistance(250)
  .size([parseInt(svg.style('width')), parseInt(svg.style('height'))]);
```

Later on down the road I'm binding nodes like this:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(scope.nodes);
var nodeg = node.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .on('click', function (n) {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + n.x + ', ' + n.y + ') scale(1.5)')
  })
  .call(force.drag);
```

The code I'm **trying** to implement is this:

```
.on('click', function (n) {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + n.x + ', ' + n.y + ') scale(1.5)')
})
```

I thought, based on some research I've done, that this would cause the node to scale or zoom when clicked. However, even though the code executes, nothing is happening. When looking at the Elements page I don't even see the transform added.

I wonder if this is because of the constantly changing transform applied by the `Force Layout`? It's effectively overriden maybe?

At any rate, ***the goal is to get this node to scale.*** It has an `image` and a couple `text` objects inside of it added like this:

```
nodeg.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
    return d.avatar || 'https://github.com/favicon.ico'
  })
  .attr("x", -56)
  .attr("y", -8)
  .attr("width", 64)
  .attr("height", 64);

nodeg.append("text")
  .attr("dx", 12)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr('class', 'name')
  .text(function (d) {
    var name;

    if (d._id === scope.user.profile._id) {
      name = 'You';
    } else if (d.firstName) {
      name = d.firstName;
      if (d.lastName) {
        name += ' ' + d.lastName;
      }
    } else if (d.lastName) {
      name = d.lastName;
    }

    return name;
  });

nodeg.append("text")
  .attr("dx", 12)
  .attr("dy", "1.35em")
  .text(function (d) {
    return d.relationship;
  });
```

## `tick` function

```
      force.on("tick", function () {
        link.attr("x1", function (d) {
          return d.source.x;
        })
          .attr("y1", function (d) {
            return d.source.y;
          })
          .attr("x2", function (d) {
            return d.target.x;
          })
          .attr("y2", function (d) {
            return d.target.y;
          });

        node.attr("transform", function (d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });
      });
```

Comment: The `force.drag` behaviour installs its own click handlers and it sounds like it's overwriting the one you're installing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749182/how-to-register-multiple-external-listeners-to-the-same-selection-in-d3 for how to have multiple handlers on the same element.

Comment: Oh and what's your `tick` handler function? Are you setting the `transform` attribute in that as well?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, you're right on there, I am setting the `transform` in the `tick`; and I'm still trying to figure out how that `tick` is fired. Clearly a bit of a black box for me still; let me post the `tick`.

Comment: The `tick` handler function is called by the force layout internally at every iteration of the layout. You can set `n.fixed = true` in your click handler to stop the layout moving the node, but you'll have to check that in the `tick` handler as well before overwriting `transform`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff you're basically brilliant! I set the `n.fixed = true` and by doing that adding the `scale` inside the click actually works without issue!

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't really work as you're overwriting `transform` in the `tick` handler function.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I did find that while the layout is still settling it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, this will only work once the `tick` event isn't fired anymore. I see you found a solution -- another would be to nest several `g` elements for each node so that you can set `scale` and `transform` independently.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff that makes sense, so I could make the `node` like it is now, but then nest a `g` inside of it, and then add the `image` and `text` to it. I'm going to consider that as it may be a lot more straight forward!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lars, once again, I've got a beautiful solution! I added a new function that builds the appropriate `transform`:

```
function getNodeTransform(n) {
  var transform = 'translate(' + n.x + ', ' + n.y + ')';
  if (n.fixed === true) {
    console.log('Adding scale to node:', n);
    transform += ' scale(1.4)';
  }
  return transform;
}
```

The next step was to use that in both the click **and** the `tick`:

```
.on('click', function (n) {
  n.fixed = !n.fixed;

  d3.select(this)
    .transition('bounce')
    .attr('transform', getNodeTransform(n));
})

force.on("tick", function () {
  link.attr("x1", function (d) {
    return d.source.x;
  })
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  node.attr("transform", function (d) {
    return getNodeTransform(d);
  });
});
```

This allows me to select nodes even while the layout is settling.