# NVD3 - Adding extra functionality to legend click without overriding existing

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

I have a NVD3 donut chart where I need a new functionality while a legend is clicked added to the Show/Hide series functionality. Could anyone please help to achieve this. However I have achieved the additional functionality as explained in below demo. But the default Legend Click functionality got vanished. Please help me.. Thanks.

```js
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var donutChart = nv.models.pieChart()
    .x(function(d) {
        return d.label
      })
    .y(function(d) {
        return d.value
      })
    .showLabels(true)
    .showLegend(true)
    .labelThreshold(.05)
    .labelType("key")
    .color(["#965251", "#00b3ca", "#7dd0b6", "#e38690", "#ead98b"])
    
    .donut(true)
    .donutRatio(0.35);
  
   // Insert text into the center of the donut
   function centerText() {
   return function() {
        var svg = d3.select("svg");

      var donut = svg.selectAll("g.nv-slice").filter(
          function (d, i) {
            return i == 0;
          }
        );
        
        // Insert first line of text into middle of donut pie chart
        donut.insert("text", "g")
            .text("Line One")
            .attr("class", "middle")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("dy", "-.55em")
          .style("fill", "#000");
        // Insert second line of text into middle of donut pie chart
        donut.insert("text", "g")
            .text("Line Two")
            .attr("class", "middle")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("dy", ".85em")
          .style("fill", "#000");
      }
    }
  
  // Put the donut pie chart together
  d3.select("#donut-chart svg")
    .datum(seedData())
    .transition().duration(300)
    .call(donutChart)
    .call(centerText());
    //.call(pieSlice());
    d3.select("g.nv-legendWrap").selectAll("g.nv-series")
                .on("click", function (d) {
                    console.log("One needs to be handled " + d.label);
                    
                })
  return donutChart;
});


// Seed data to populate donut pie chart
function seedData() {
  return [
    {
      "label": "One",
      "value": 25
    },
    {
      "label": "Two",
      "value": 25
    },
    {
      "label": "Three",
      "value": 25
    },
    {
      "label": "Four",
      "value": 25
    },
    {
      "label": "Five",
      "value": 25
    }
  ];
}
```

```css
html, body, #donut-chart, .content{height:100%;width:100%;}
.content h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
}

svg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;

   text.middle {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  
  .nvd3.nv-pie .nv-pieLabels text {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    fill: #fff !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.4/nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.4/nv.d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <h1>NVD3 Donut Pie Chart</h1>
  
  <div id="donut-chart">
    <svg></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could add a namespace to the event's name like `"click.my"`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14753683.

Comment: altocumulus - That worked.. Thanks. This might be a simple javascript tweek which I was not striken with..

Comment: No, it's not a standard JS feature. This is handled by D3 instead. Check the API docs for more details.

Comment: Oh Thats Great!

Answer (score 0):

Replacing,

```
d3.select("g.nv-legendWrap").selectAll("g.nv-series")
            .on("click", function (d) {
                console.log("One needs to be handled " + d.label);

            })
```

with

```
d3.select("g.nv-legendWrap").selectAll("g.nv-series")
            .on("click.namespace", function (d) {
                console.log("One needs to be handled " + d.label);

            })
```

worked.. Thanks altocumulus.